# Registering call to object factory causes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, objectfactory

I'm trying to build a simple object factory in c++. So far i have this code:

The Factory:

```cpp
class Factory{
    public:
        TCreateMethod = std::function<Simulation*(std::string)>;
    public:
        Factory() = delete;

        static bool Register(const std::string name, TCreateMethod funcCreate){
            const auto [it, success] = s_methods.insert({name, funcCreate});
            return success;
        };

        static Simulation* Create(const std::string name, const std::string ini_file){
            if (auto it = s_methods.find(name); it != s_methods.end()){
                return it->second(ini_file);
            }
            return nullptr;
        };

    private:
        static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod> s_methods;
};

std::map<std::string, Factory::TCreateMethod> Factory::s_methods;
```

The Object:

```cpp
class SimulationStuff : public Simulation{
    public:
        SimulationStuff(std::string ini_file);

        static Simulation* createMethod(std::string ini_file){
            return new SimulationStuff(ini_file);
        };

        static std::string getFactoryName(){
            return "SimulationStuff";
        };

    private
        static bool s_registerd;
};

bool SimulationStuff::s_registered = Factory::Register(SimulationStuff::getFactoryName(), SimulationStuff::createMethod);
```

Backtrace of the segv:

```
#0  0x00007ffff75ae44a in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00005555556192a1 in std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > >::operator--() (this=0x7fffffffd820)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_tree.h:302
#2  0x0000555555618e36 in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (this=0x5555557bc180 <Factory::s_methods[abi:cxx11]>, __k="SimulationStuff")
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_tree.h:2063
#3  0x0000555555618b05 in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > > >::_M_insert_unique<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > >(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> >&&) (this=0x5555557bc180 <Factory::s_methods[abi:cxx11]>, __v=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_tree.h:2106
#4  0x00005555556188b2 in std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> > > >::insert(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)> >&&) (
    this=0x5555557bc180 Factory::s_methods[abi:cxx11]>, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_map.h:809
#5  0x00005555556184ab in Factory::Register(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::function<Simulation* (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>) (name="SimulationStuff", funcCreate=...)
    at src/factory.cpp:13
#6  0x000055555560ca19 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at src/simulation_stuff.cpp:24
#7  0x000055555560ca7e in _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN28SimulationStuff12s_registeredE () at src/simulation_stuff.cpp:73
#8  0x00005555556c3d75 in __libc_csu_init ()
#9  0x00007ffff71aa02a in __libc_start_main (main=0x55555569f7eb <main(int, char**)>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb88, init=0x5555556c3d30 <__libc_csu_init>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdb78) at ../csu/libc-start.c:264
#10 0x00005555555a5a6a in _start ()
```

The Problem I have is that I'm unable to understand why the segv is happening as the `s_methods` map should be 0 initialized at compiletime and `s_registered` should be initialized at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run afoul of the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).  The order of initialization of objects with static lifetime (such as globals and static class members) that are defined in different compilation units is unspecified.  It's entirely possible for `SimulationStuff::s_registered` to be initialized before `Factory::s_methods`.  If that happens then your `std::map` isn't initialized when you attempt to insert into it.

To work around this, construct your registry map on first use.  i.e.:

```
class Factory {
        // ...
        static std::map<std::string, TCreateMethod>& getMethods() {
            static std::map<std::string, TCreateMehtod> methods;
            return methods;
        }

        static bool Register(const std::string name, TCreateMethod funcCreate){
            const auto [it, success] = getMethods().insert({name, funcCreate});
            return success;
        };
        // ...
};
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. As i have understoud the static initialization order fiasco is that one only has to worry about it if statics are dynamicaly initialized. The map as i see it should be const initalized and so be initalized on compilation and not on program start. is that wrong or can't maps be const initialized?

Comment: `std::map` is a class type, so it gets default-initialized on program startup.  That means its default constructor needs to be called to initialize its internal structures (usually a red-black tree).